# Mysql stored procedure where clause

Tags: php, sql, mysql, stored-procedures

Ok let me try this again.

query("CALL getemployee('$eml')");
$result = $sql->fetch_array();
?>
This is my stored procedure:

```
Delimiter //
Create procedure getemployee(in eml varchar(50))
Begin
  Select * from employees where email = eml;
End//
Delimiter ;
```

The error i get from browser:
"Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object ...".

I use phpmyadmin version 3.2.4 and the mysql client version: 5.1.41

Comment: Showing your PHP code would make it easier to help.

Comment: I do not see where `eml` is declared or set in your procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Your [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html) statement appears to be invalid.

You need to give a name to your procedure, and to the parameter that you are passing. Therefore you may want to try something like the following example:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE procName (IN eml varchar(50))
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM employees WHERE email = eml;
END//    
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `eml` variable you use is not defined. Should not it be as following:

```
Create procedure getemployee (in eml varchar(50))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_customers(IN inCustomerIdList VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN

  SELECT first_name, last_name, email FROM tbl_customers  
  WHERE customer_id IN (inCustomerIdList);

END$$
```